# Center li of nav bar vertically

Tags: html, css, nav, centering

[image]

As you can see the menu points are not centered vertically like the social media points, could someone please tell me how to do that, it's the first page I am working on. I would also like to scale down the space between the social media links, would be very grateful if someone could help me!

```css
.menu-link {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #262a2b;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 45px;
}

#social-media {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-link:hover {
  color: #0088a9;
}

.active-menu-links {
  color: white;
}

#normal-header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 19px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#header-img {
  height: 110px;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

#nav-bar {}

#nav-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

#nav-bar li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
}

#nav-bar ul,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#hero-header" class="menu-link"> Home </a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#features-container" class="menu-link"> About </a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#presentation-container" class="menu-link"> Roadmap </a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#main-media-container" class="menu-link"> Ecosystem </a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#prices-section-container" class="menu-link"> Team </a>
      <li>

        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"><img id="social-media" src="xxx" alt="Instagram"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"><img id="social-media" src="xxx" alt="Twitter"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"><img id="social-media" src="xxx" alt="Discord"></a>
        </li>
        -->
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use padding and margins for this.

Comment: Try line-height.

Comment: if you put a border on .#nav-bar {} you'll see the contents aligned vertically (by the way) .. I mean in your snippet. I was editing your question before to add a snippet instead of static code and while spending time to better format your html I did that try and canceled my revision because I didn't want to change any detail of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I can't identify your problem because the snippet not working well as missing of files

But you can try to add `align-items: center;` to the `#nav-bar ul` selector

Or you can add `display: flex` `align-items: center;` to the `#nav-bar li`

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- Set `line-height` property of `li` or `li a` to the overall height
- Set `vertical-align: middle;` (this doesn't always work for me)
- Use paddings and margins (not recommended)
- Set `display: flex;` and `align-items: center` to your `li` tag, but it can potentially break your layout

Answer (score 0):

Since you made a snippet I tried and yes, you need line-height.✌️

*To explain: If you use line-height with the same height as it's element. The two will match and make a easy menu button. Some side padding and/or margin, and you are done.*

```css
.menu-link {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #262a2b;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

#social-media {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-link:hover {
  color: #0088a9;
}

.active-menu-links {
  color: white;
}

#normal-header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 19px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#header-img {
  height: 110px;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

#nav-bar {}

#nav-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

#nav-bar li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
}

#nav-bar ul,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#hero-header" class="menu-link"> Home </a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#features-container" class="menu-link"> About </a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#presentation-container" class="menu-link"> Roadmap </a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#main-media-container" class="menu-link"> Ecosystem </a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="menu-item"><a href="#prices-section-container" class="menu-link"> Team </a>
      <li>

        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"><img id="social-media" src="xxx" alt="Instagram"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"><img id="social-media" src="xxx" alt="Twitter"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="xxx"><img id="social-media" src="xxx" alt="Discord"></a>
        </li>
        -->
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I wonder how it did change respect to the original one because they look the same

Comment: that's not a valid comment frankly. I was telling you that if you run the original snippet, it already looked correctly aligned vertically so any modification was not needed unless you explain why line-height would change anything if any condition would change in the contents. This race for getting the answer done is very annoying because it doesn't address the real problem and makes people say things without even checking

Comment: you can’t tell me that I didn’t look good enough if I’m telling you that the final result looks the same. YOU didn’t look good enough not me. I know very well how styling works but surely your answer before was not explaining anything but just saying that your snippet now looked good compared to the original. But the original already looked good. yes you had to explain because that’s how SO is supposed to work. You say you checked but again it seems like you never checked the original

Comment: I did.. even after you comment I triple checked. Open my snippet.. run.. hold your fingernail under the font.. remove line-height.. and run again. 

Comment: I give you a suggestion… remove line-height and add border to the navmap. you’ll see it’s already aligned vertically. so not only you didn’t produce a better solution for the case shown in the snippet but you even made the height higher probably. I’m being repeating this ten times since the first comment on the original question: in the original snippet the alignment its correct. nothing more. now I hope you understand what I’m trying to tell you. I’m not blaming for the sake of nothing. I had good reasons